# In perforce, how do I remove pending changes for NEW/ADDED files not submitted?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to remove a pending changelist in perforce. All the files (20 old) are new but have not be committed/submitted yet. So in p4Win, they show a RED + cross. I am failing to remove these files from the change list. How do I go about getting rid of these files?

Thanks for the answers to right-click and revert. I have tried that but it fails with the example error strings below.

```
Operation: user-revert
Librarian digest source/.../foo.c failed.
RCS checkout 1.715484 failed!
RCS no such revision 1.715484!
//source/.../foo.c#1 - was add, reverted
```

I've also tried the p4 revert command but it fails with same error(s).

Comment: The final comment would seem to indicate that the revert worked, but I assume that the file is still on the changelist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed with "revert -k" by perforce support group. They suspect it may be due to overlay values in the client workspace but have not been very specific.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.  From "p4 help revert":  "The -k flag marks the file as reverted in server metadata without altering files in the client workspace."

Answer (score 7):

How are you trying to remove the files?

It's been a while since I used Perforce in anger but I seem to remember that you just had to right click and revert the file.

I've just tried this and it worked OK for me (the programmer's lament!). It uses the following p4 command:

> p4 revert //depot/test.txt

Where test.txt is the name of the test file.

**Update**

Does the new file still exist locally on your hard drive?

Does the path where the file would be in the depot still exist? ie. what's in the "..." of your path.

Comment: Yes. The new file stil exists locally on the hard drive

Comment: I'm running out of ideas :(. Does the depot location still exist?

Comment: Thanks ChrisF. Really appreciate the help. It is a new file so does not exist in any depot location as I had not submitted yet.

Comment: I was thinking of the path where it would exist - but Perforce should be able to cope with that not existing, so my question is meaningless - sorry. Is the number the same every time? I don't understand where that's come from.

Comment: You mean the number "1.715484", right? Yes it is the same even for different files

Comment: I'd take this up with Perforce support. When we used it in the past their support was very good. I'm still using an old version so anything else I suggest may well be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Revert files, right-click on file in change list and select revert, this will remove added files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Perforce support at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all added files in current and sub directories:

```
p4 revert ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because the RCS files (the actual files with ,v extension in the depot that contain all the revision information) were literally missing the information for the revision in question.  I was able to restore the files from backup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had added the .exe files but wanted to exclude them afterwards. The perforce documentation helped:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4eclipse/topics/adding.html

**Excluding Files from Source Control**

> Important: you cannot exclude files after you have placed them under
>   Perforce control. If you have files opened in a changelist and you
>   want to exclude them from Perforce control, revert them from the
>   changelist before excluding them.

Worked like a charm.